# PM2 downloads in idea are complete but can't start

Tags: node.js, pm2

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

pm2 downloads have been successful, but it's always impossible to start. The input (`PM2 start app.js`) is reported as follows: 'pm2' is not an internal or external command, nor is it a running program.

I hope to help me solve it. Thank you.

Comment: A picture of an error message in Chinese(?) is not useful here, only English is used. And code and error messages should be posted as text.

Comment: Please explain what your problem is and what you have tried to do to fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't make it clear. I got it.@Mat.

Comment: I made a change and I'm sorry for @Andrew Eisenberg

Comment: Syntax and format are correct, and will not be related to the configuration environment of node.js. Andrew Eisenberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like pm2 is not on your path. Most likely, your entire node global install directory is not on your path. What you need to do is the following:

1. Determine where the node global install location is. It looks like you are on windows, so it might be something like `C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin`. I am not sure though, so you need to find it yourself.
2. Add this folder to your PATH. [See this answer on how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546345/172363)

Then you should be able to launch pm2 from any command prompt.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Andrew Eisenberg. The environment configuration is wrong. What do I need to do to improve your reputation?